# How to resize a 'image' with negative numbers using scipy.misc.resize?

Tags: opencv, scipy, computer-vision

I want to resize a surface normal 'image' (H*W*3). The problem is that there are negetive numbers in the array. How can I use the `scipy.misc.resize` or `cv2.resize` to resize this?

Comment: Do those methods not work with negative numbers? That would be weird... If that is actually the case, try subtracting the minimum value in the array, and then add it again after resizing.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.resize` supports negative numbers.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

a = np.full((5, 5, 3), -5, float))
b = cv2.resize(a, (10, 10))
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[[[-5. -5. -5.]  
  [-5. -5. -5.]  
  [-5. -5. -5.]...
```

---

It could be that you are having a problem using `cv2.resize` because the type of your image is `int32`.
`cv2.resize` does not support `int32` type.

The following code raises an exception:

```
a = np.full((5, 5, 3), -5, np.int32)
b = cv2.resize(a, (10, 10))
```

You may convert the image to type `np.int16` before resizing:

```
a = np.full((5, 5, 3), -5, np.int32)
b = cv2.resize(a.astype(np.int16), (10, 10))
```

---

There is no `scipy.misc.resize`, there is [scipy.misc.imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html), but method is deprecated:

> imresize is deprecated! imresize is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.3.0. Use Pillow instead

It looks like there is some control over the range, using `mode` argument.